# How to disable Skype spell check in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, skype

Skype just had an update on my Windows 7 machine and now **it's checking for english spelling** but like millions of other people, I speak multiple languages so it's a very irritating feature with no obvious way to change language or turn it off. I'm sure I'm not the only one either.

Does anyone here knows how can this be turned off?

Things I've tried:

- I've posted a ticket to Skype but skeptical of any feedback, have more hopes in superuser.
- Looked at documentation and you can find step by step instructions for turning it off but for Windows 8.1 and 10 only. It appears they made it so it's turned off/on exclusively on operating system level.
- Looked through the new settings menu which contains a sum total of 1 options for the chat window, unfortunately not the one I need.

If I find a solution I'll post it for others.

Note: There is an option to change the language to other than "device language" which changes the UI language as well. But then it checks against that language only, does not help if you constantly write multiple languages or if you don't want any kind of spell checking.

Here's how it looks after the latest update:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. It can't be enabled or disabled from Skype and the setting at the OS level is only available on Windows 8.1 or 10.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_windesk-skype_messms-skype_instamessms/skype-812-spell-check-windows-7/16810956-663c-431c-8fd4-b0566c24f5c6

Comment: This is the correct answer, unfortunately. The only "workaround" is to specify at least some language (there are plenty) but lots of people write in multiple languages so it really fascinates me how this hasn't occurred to Microsoft in this time and age.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to remove (or rename, or make unaccessable for the program) the file spellchecker.node in the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules@paulcbetts\spellchecker\build\Release".